# Why does my RewriteRule not work when there is a `?` in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am learning how to write regular expressions for .htaccess redirects.
So far I've managed to figure out everything I needed, except for a couple of regular expressions which don't behave as I expected. I am testing my regular expressions using a desktop application, and they work fine there, but not in the .htaccess file.

FYI: The RewriteBase is set to `/site/`

This is the incoming URL:
`/site/view-by-tag/politics/?el_mcal_month=3&el_mcal_year=2009`

I want to grab "politics" and redirect to `/site/tags/politics/`

Here is what I used:

`RewriteRule ^view-by-tag/([a-zA-Z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/\.\_\=\?\&]+) /tags/$1/ [R=301,L]`

I added the capture of all the characters after `politics` because I am having the issue that when there is a `?` in the URL the redirect does not work, and I can't figure out why. In the URL given above, if I remove the `?` it works fine, but if the `?` is in there, nothing happens. Is there a reason for this?

The same thing happens when I try to capture `307` from `/site/?option=com_content&view=article&id=307&catid=89&Itemid=55`

I used this regular expression, `article&id=([0-9]+) /?p=$1 [R=301,L]` but again, when there is a `?` in the URL it stops the redirect for doing anything.

What is the reason for that?

The `.htaccess` file in question is on a Wordpress blog (3.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

The query string is must be processed separately in a `RewriteCond` if you need to manipulate it, and should not be matched inside the `RewriteRule`  Instead, just match the request *not* including the query string, and use `QSA` to append the query string onto the redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^view-by-tag/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ /tags/$1/ [R=301,L,QSA]
# OR, if you don't want the rest of the query string appended, put a `?` onto 
# the redirect to replace it with nothing
RewriteRule ^view-by-tag/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ /tags/$1/? [R=301,L]
```

Actually, the `QSA` may not be needed in a `R` redirect - I think that the default behavior is to pass the query string with the redirect.

If you need to capture `307` from the query string, do it in a `RewriteCond` and capture in `%1`:

```
# Capture the id in %1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([\d]+)
# Redirect everything to /, pass %1 into p
RewriteRule . /?p=%1 [LR=301,L]
```

Comment: Ditto of my comment to TerryE: Thanks for this info. Been away for a few days. I'll try this out. Very helpful to know this. I am greatly enjoying learning more about regular expressions... something I've put off for way to long.

Comment: @inspiredlife Learning regular expressions is a principle step toward achieving enlightenment, or like beginning to see through the Matrix.

Comment: :-) .Yes, seeing through the Matrix and, perhaps more importantly, being able to manipulate and change it at will! Powerful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The point that you've missed is that the rewrite engine splits the URI into two parts:  the **REQUEST_URI** and the **QUERY_STRING**.  The query string part isn't used in the rule match string so there is no point in constructing *rule* regexp patterns to look for it.

You can probe and pick out parameters from the query string by using rewrite conditions and condition regexps to set **%N** variables.

By default the query string is appended to the output substitution string unless you have a `?someparam` in it -- in which case it is ignored *unless* you used the [QSA] (query string append) parameter.

The way that you'd pick up the id in `/site/?option=com_content&view=article&id=307&catid=89&Itemid=55` is to use something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=(\d+)
```

Before the rule and this would set `%1` to 307.  Read the [rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more general discussion of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Been away for a few days. I'll try this out. Very helpful to know this. I am greatly enjoying learning more about regular expressions... something I've put off for way to long.